# Aheadworks Followup Email

Tags: magento-enterprise, extensions

I'm using Follow Up Email extension from AheadWorks.

There is AW Review Request Per Product template in newsletter templates section contained following line code

**{{foreach var="$order.getAllVisibleItems()" template="nsltr:AW Review Request Per Product Row"}}**

Now by analyzed above code i check in AW Review Request Per Product Row template which contained following code for product url

**{{store url="catalog/product/view" id="$row_item.product.id"}}**

so when we generate test email product url returns wrong in email like http://www.localhost.com/catalog/product/view/id/1510/

but i want actual product url like http://www.localhost.com/abc.html

so can anyone help me how to achieve this functionality?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from ahedworks support team, {{var row_item.product.product_url}}
Need to use this code to get SEO friendly product URL.

Comment: Have look at this module that handle SEO friendly URL pretty well, you may have to pay but it is half priced this one.
http://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/follow-up-emails-extension.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try this variable **{{store url="$row_item.product.getUrlPath()"}}** in the Product Row template (based on the instructions [here](http://confluence.aheadworks.com/display/EUDOC/Follow+Up+Email#FollowUpEmail-Variables) )

Comment: unfortunately not. :-|

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://confluence.aheadworks.com/display/EUDOC/Follow+Up+Email#FollowUpEmail-frontend-links) for the extension states that you can use the built-in Magento variables. That being said, here is a [wiki article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_email_template/index#email_variables) describing the various variables that are available in a Magento email template. I would suggest starting with the {{ var product_url }} variable.

Short of that, the only way to test this is by having the extension. The best way to get answers when dealing with custom extensions is to contact the developer as they will have a lot more insight into what can be done because they created it.